# How do I do a set of a generic value?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following defined:

```
public class myClass<T> {
    private T value;

    protected <T> void setValue(T value) {
        if (value != null) // optional
            this.value = value;
    }
}
```

However I get a compilation error with this:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from T to T
```

(I know, helpful and logical right?).

What's the proper way to setup this method?  Also note, the signature is setup in an abstract class like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
protected abstract <T> void setValue(T value);
```

Comment: remove <T> in `protected abstract <T> void setValue(T value);`

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("hiding")` - dont. You are hiding the generic type `T` which is wrong, it is not what you want. This warning is legit and should have alerted you that you did a mistake. Dont ignore it, follow its advice and remove the second declaration of `T`.

Comment: @AndyTurner oh dear... I'm sure you can guess what happened. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two unrelated `T` types. In your method declaration, `<T>` re-declares a type `T`, hiding the class-level type variable.

In short, you don't need the method to be generic, because you want `setValue` to take the type declared on the class. Because the type parameter is available throughout the class, your method should be as simple as:

```
protected void setValue(T value) {
    if (value != null)
        this.value = value;
}
```

If your abstract class is generic too, then the same correction needs to be made in it too. Otherwise, you need to revisit its design as having a method taking randomly typed values isn't exactly right.

Comment: See my note about changing <Object> to <T> in the abstract class extension above.

Answer (score 1):

You already have defined T at class level, if you put it again in the method it takes it as another T. Look at the error message I get when trying to compile your code.

```
MyClass.java:6: error: incompatible types: T#1 cannot be converted to T#2
        this.value = value;
                     ^
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>setValue(T#1)
    T#2 extends Object declared in class MyClass
1 error
```

Just remove the second declaration of T and it will compile as intended.

```java
public class MyClass<T> {
    private T value;

    protected void setValue(T value) {
        if (value != null) {
            this.value = value;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue was that I had defined the following:

public class MyClass<T> extends MyClassAbstract<Object>...  changing the Abstract extension  from <Object> to <T> fixed the issue in the override of the abstract class. otherwise, it insists that the signatures do not match.